# C++ How pointer's memory address and pointed array's memory address can be same?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-address, stack-memory

In this code `ar` and `&ar` same. But isn't `ar`just a constant pointer to `ar[0]`?Then I suppose writing `cout<<ar;` should give `ar[0]`'s memory adress while writing `cout<<&ar;` should give it's own memory adress so they should be different. How they are same? Some say `ar` is not a pointer than how `cout<<*ar` is equal to `ar[0]`'s value if it is not a pointer to `ar[0]` ?

```
int ar[3] = {1,2,3};
cout<<ar<<endl;
cout<<&ar<<endl;
```

I mean in this code `&a` and `&b` are different which makes sense.

```
   int a = 5;
    int* b = &a;
    cout<<&a<<endl;
    cout<<&b<<endl;
```

Comment: No, `arr` is not a pointer, it is an `array of  3 ints`. It can be implicitly converted to `pointer to int` though.

Comment: yeah, @VTT is right, `arr` is an array. Although it does contain the address of the first element, it cannot be considered as a pointer. I think whenever we use it in place of pointer, it simply decays to just a pointer.

Comment: How *ar is equal to ar[0]'s value if it is not a pointer to ar[0]

Comment: This is a very good question. Array or pointer this is not so important. Why its own address is equal to its value???

Comment: `*ar` will actually be equivalent to the following: `int * tmp_p_ar_items{static_cast<int *>(ar)}; *(tmp_p_ar_items);` while `ar[0]` will actually be equivalent to the following: `int * tmp_p_ar_items{static_cast<int *>(ar)}; *(tmp_p_ar_items + 0);`. You can check that array is not a pointer by comparing `sizeof(ar)` to `sizeof(int *)` or by using `std::is_same`

Comment: @VTT Looks like you're answering the question. Looks like a pretty good answer, too. Go ahead - submit an answer.

Comment: @Igid Nah, this question will be definitely closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
int ar[3] = {1,2,3};
```

`ar` here is an "array designator" wich *automatically casted* to pointer to the first array element.
`ar` is equivalent to `&a[0]`. So that `ar` has a type `int *`

`&ar` ia a pointer to *whole array* and has type `int (*)[3]`

The following code is valid (pointers are compatible)

```
int *par0 = ar;
int (*par)[3] = &ar;
```

Although `a` and `&a` have different types, they have the same value — addresses of  the first array element and array as a whole is the same.

Comment: `ar` has type `int[3]`